# Python, roll 2 dice and sum up the outcomes 10000 times, present in histogram

Tags: python, montecarlo

Question is to use Monte carlo sample for throw of 10000 dice pairs of 10-faced dice, sum each pair, count the occurrence of each outcome and plot in histogram.

This is my code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r1=r2=r3=r4=r5=r6=r7=r8=r9=r10=r11=r12=r13=r14=r15=r16=r17=r18=r19=r20=0

for i in range(0,10000):
    d1=random.randint(1,10)
    d2=random.randint(1,10)
    roll=d1+d2
    if roll==2:
        r2+=1
    elif roll==3:
        r3+=1
    elif roll==4:
        r4+=1
    elif roll==5:
        r5+=1
    if roll==6:
        r6+=1
    elif roll==7:
        r7+=1
    elif roll==8:
        r8+=1
    elif roll==9:
        r9+=1
    elif roll==10:
        r10+=1
    elif roll==11:
        r11+=1
    elif roll==12:
        r12+=1
    elif roll==13:
        r13+=1
    elif roll==14:
        r14+=1
    elif roll==15:
        r15+=1
    elif roll==16:
        r16+=1
    elif roll==17:
        r17+=1
    elif roll==18:
        r18+=1
    elif roll==19:
        r19+=1
    elif roll==20:
        r20+=1
    else:
        roll=0

rollresults=r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r13,r14,r15,r16,r17,r18,r19,r20
print(rollresults)


data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
counted_data = {1:float(r1),2:float(r2),3:float(r3),4:float(r4),5:float(r5),6:float(r6),7:float(r7),8:float(r8),9:float(r9),10:float(r10),11:float(r11),12:float(r12),13:float(r13),14:float(r14),15:float(r15),16:float(r16),17:float(r17),18:float(r18),19:float(r19),20:float(r20)}
hh=plt.hist(data,bins=len(data),rwidth=.95,)
hh1=plt.hist(counted_data.keys(), weights=counted_data.values(),bins=range(1,21), rwidth=.95, label="counted_data",align='left')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It works but is there any way to simplify it as if I were to increase the number of dice, the code would be very long.

The histogram plotted correctly but the next few questions are with more than two dices. I think a more concise code would be better but im unsure of how to do that.

Comment: Use a list to store the results.

Comment: Better yet, use a `dict`.

Comment: @ScottHunter They even already do...

Answer (score -1):

You can use `collections.Counter()` to get the counts of each roll. And you can use `sum()` with a generator to handle variable number of dice.

```
import collections, random
num_dice = 2
num_faces = 10
num_rolls = 1000

counted_data = collections.Counter(
    sum(random.randint(1, num_faces) for die in range(num_dice))
    for roll in range(num_rolls)
)
```